# How to transform a JSON object typescript conform?

Tags: json, typescript

I need to transform a JSON reponse from :

```
[
    {
        "value": {
            "name": "Actions",
            "visible": true,
            "property": "actions"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": {
            "name": "Checkbox",
            "visible": true,
            "property": "checkbox"
        }
    }
]
```

to :

```
[
    {
   
        "name": "Actions",
        "visible": true,
        "property": "actions"
    
    },
     {
        "name": "Checkbox",
        "visible": true,
        "property": "checkbox"
        
    }
]
```

What is the "best" way to achieve this and remove the key "value" ?

Is it a foreach loop or are the other ways ? Trying to learn new ways as well

Best, Peter

Comment: Best based on what criteria? Fastest code execution? Least lines of code? Lowest memory footprint? Some metric that combines all 3 criteria and weighs their importance in an undisclosed way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete definition. I should have used a different word . This is why is put it into quotes. But your are right. As I am still learning TS I was just open to different approaches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the build in [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to achieve this:

```
let array = [
{
    "value": {
        "name": "Actions",
        "visible": true,
        "property": "actions"
    }
},
{
    "value": {
        "name": "Checkbox",
        "visible": true,
        "property": "checkbox"
    }
   }
 ]

let mapped_aray = array.map(x => x.value);
```